# Any finger scanning sample tutorial iPhone sdk

Tags: ios

I have been seeing many apps on appstore concerning finger scan. I would like to get a tutorial how it works or if any free/paid sdk available. The goal behind is to use finger scanning as login instead the person has to login every time with a username/password.

Many thanks. :)

Comment: I think most of these applications are fake and just for entertaining, also it won't be possible to "scan" a fingerprint with your iOS device …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. You can't get the user fingerprint through the iPhone screen.

In fact, the apps you mentioned are fake (and even scams if they try to make users believe they can indeed scan their fingerprint).

Comment: thanks for advice but how this app works https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fingerprint-scanner/id511075080?l=ru&ls=1&mt=8

Comment: @Hrushikesh the one you provided is a scam. Also, in it's description, it states clearly that it is for entertainment purposes only.

Answer (score 2):

All of these apps are just for entertainment. None of them is actually scanning your finger, the screen isn't that good. I think that they do it by adding some gesture recognizer and waiting for a tap. And then one of many random fingerprints will just appear on the screen. If you check it a few times you will see that your finger will have different fingerprints.

So don't even try to use that for authentication. As an option: remember username/password in `NSUserDefaults` and connect immediately with it when the app Launches

Comment: thanks for advice but how this app works https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fingerprint-scanner/id511075080?l=ru&ls=1&mt=8

Comment: @Hrushikesh try to read the description of the app: *This app is intended for **entertainment purposes only** and does not provide true fingerprint scan functionality. This is the best fingerprint scanner you can find in the AppStore! Realistic detection animation and perfect sound will help you **prank** your friends!*