# can we capture fingerprint presented on iphone screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any finger scanning sample tutorial iPhone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276186/any-finger-scanning-sample-tutorial-iphone-sdk)

i say a one app in appstore **Fingerprint Security**
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fingerprint-security-pro/id312912865?mt=8

and i say a video in youtube
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GWagOcy35A&noredirect=1

is it possible to capture fingerprint?
if yes can any one tell me how to get that.
and which sdk supports?

plz.. plz...

Answer (score 1):

No. To capture a finger print, you need a scanner/camera of some sort. The iPhone screen is neither of those.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all, that is one app that is meant only for entertainment. It can't be done. The appstore link even gives you instructions on how to perform this "trick".

Answer (score 0):

From the Fingerprint Security page: "This app is intended for entertainment purposes only and does not provide security functionality. "

The iPhone screen can not read the details of a fingerprint, only touch/no-touch.